# Bitcoin Core ZMQ "hashTx"

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, bitcoind, hash, zeromq

Bitcoin Core ZMQ messaging system has `hashtx` along with 4 other topics. But nowhere it is documented whether the transactions that comes from `hashtx` are confirmed transactions which are added in a block or unconfirmed transactions that is yet to mined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both. A notification will be sent when a transaction is added to the mempool. For newly added blocks, a notification will be sent for every transaction in that block, so when a transaction is confirmed, there will be a notification for it.

Comment: Thanks @Andrew, So two notification will be coming, one when sent to mempool and another when it got added in the block right ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.